# How can I remove a specific character from multi line string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string which looks like this:

```
st = '''emp:firstinfo\n
       :secondinfo\n
       thirdinfo
     '''
print(st)
```

What I am trying to do is to skip the second ':' from my string, and get an output which looks like this:

```
'''emp:firstinfo\n
   secondinfo\n
   thirdinfo
   '''
```

simply put if it starts with a ':' I'm trying to ignore it.

Here's what I've done:

```
mat_obj = re.match(r'(.*)\n*([^:](.*))\n*(.*)' , st)
print(mat_obj.group())
```

Clearly, I don't see my mistake but could anyone please help me telling where I am getting it wrong?

Comment: What exactly distinguishes where the `:` you want to remove is? Will it always be the second `:` in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` with this regex:

```
>>> print (re.sub(r'([^:\n]*:[^:\n]*\n)\s*:(.+)', r'\1\2', st))
emp:firstinfo
secondinfo

       thirdinfo
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4LIdw5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start 1st capture group

  - `[^:\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `:` and newline
  - `:`: Match a colon
  - `[^:\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `:` and newline
  - `\n`: Match a new line
- `)`: End 1st capture group
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `:`: Match a colon
- `(.+)`: Match 1 or more of any characters (except newlines) in 2nd capture group
- `\1\2`: Is used in **replacement** to put back substring captured in groups 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub instead, just don't capture the undesired part.

```
(.*\n)[^:]*:(.*\n)(.*)
```

[image]

Replace by

```
\1\2\3
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/gbcFN3/3/)

---

```
import re

regex = r"(.*\n)[^:]*:(.*\n)(.*)"

test_str = ("emp:firstinfo\\n\n"
    "       :secondinfo\\n\n"
    "       thirdinfo")

subst = "\\1\\2\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import regex library
```

import re

```
#remove character in a String and replace with empty string.
```

text = "The film Pulp Fiction was released in year 1994"
result = re.sub(r"[a-z]", "", text)
print(result)